# RegEx match certain string until next occurence of this string

Tags: java, regex

I need to match a string (let's name it "/export/home") and everything that follows (including optional new lines) until the next occurence of this string.

I tried /(/export/home.*\n*.*)(.)*/ but it won't match the correct set from string to string.

Example:

```
/export/home/bla "123" "bla" test 1
/export/home/bla "123" "bla" test 2
/export/home/bla "123" "bla" test 3
test4
test5
/export/home/bla "123" "bla" test 6
/export/home/bla "123" "bla" test 7
/export/home/bla "123" "bla" test 8
test9
/export/home/bla "123" "bla" test 1
```

Everything and including from /export/home until the next /export/home should be matched.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
(?s)/export/home(?:(?!/export/home\b).)*
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qxx01p/2)

The `(?s)` will make `.` match any char including line break chars, `/export/home`  will match `/export/home`and `(?:(?!/export/home).)*` will match any char (`.`), zero or more occurrences (`*`) that does not start a `/export/home` literal char sequence.

If you [unroll](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) the pattern, it will look like

```
/export/home/[^/]*(?:/(?!export/home/)[^/]*)*
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qxx01p/3)

Comment: Thank you sir! Now I'm working on fully understanding this pattern :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.